# ES6 imports for JWT

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, npm, jwt

I'm making a nodeJS web app and I'm using JWT for authentication. All my work is in ES6 modules and I wanted to import JWT in the same way, but apparently it isn't yet supported by the package. I can't use the older require() format as it throws an error since I've set it to modules in my package.json. Is there a way around this or do I have to find another library altogether?

Edit: I have fixed the issue with destructuring but it's still not working. Apparently it can't find the module at all. I made sure the package is in fact installed and updated, still not working

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'jsonwebtoken' imported from /path/to/file.js

```
import jwt from ' jsonwebtoken'
const { sign } = jwt

class sampleClass {

   static func(user) {
      return sign(
            {
                _id: user._id,
                name: user.name,
            },
            'sample key',
            {
                expiresIn: '7d',
            },
      )
   }

}
```

Comment: did you try to execute your file with the experimental flag `node --experimental-modules app.js`

Comment: No way you cant use es6 import, you doing it wrong.

Comment: Yes, ES6 import functionality is working with all other packages, the issue is with JWT as it does not support ES6 imports, the issue has been raised on github but no solution other than modifying the package manually, which leads to a massive package size.

Comment: Are you kidding me? I just installed jwt and everything is fine.
Im not sure what did you try to do, post you code.

Comment: I have updated and getting a new error apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try something:

1. Create a folder
2. Do `npm init`
3. Create a file `app.js`
4. install json web token `npm i jsonwebtoken`
5. Go to `package.json` and add `"type": "module"`
6. write in your `app.js` this here: `import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"`
7. Execute it: `node --experimental-modules app.js`

Tell me then if you get an error

Comment: Apparently it isn't finding the package at all now, I have updated the question with the error I'm getting

Comment: That solved it somehow, I guess I'll just copy the files over to the new project folder

Answer (score 10):

Your gonna need to import it and then assign it like this

```js
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
const { sign, verify } = jwt;
const token = sign({"d":"dd"}, "secret", {expiresIn: 300})
console.log(token);
const verifycode = verify(token, "secret");
console.log(verifycode);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jwt v8, just import the jsonwebtoken this way:

`import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'`

or

`import { sign, decode, verify } from 'jsonwebtoken'`

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra space in `import jwt from ' jsonwebtoken'`

Should just be `import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'`

I just tested it and it works fine on my computer

Answer (score 1):

I am using typescript to write my node server and jwt implementation.

This is the suggestion on my terminal:

Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jsonwebtoken` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'jsonwebtoken';

I just typed: `npm i --save-dev @types/jsonwebtoken`

Then in my file I added imports: `import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
const jwt = Jwt;
```

I can use it like this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!