# What does the export function javascript error mean and how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

so I'm trying to call the function jsonToAim(), which is created in a.js, in another script b.js

this is how I defined it in a.js:

```
export function jsonToAim(jsonObj){...}
```

this is how I called it in b.js

```
const backend = require('./a')`
let aimObj = backend.jsonToAim(jsonObj);
```

I ended up getting this error:

```
export function jsonToAim(jsonObj){
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:992:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:941:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:782:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/create-aims/getAim.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1076:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
```

does anyone know where I went wrong? sorry if this is a stupid question i'm super new to js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js - SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

Comment: Use `module.exports.jsonToAim = () => {};`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to `export` stuff in JS... e.g., the CommonsJS vs ES6 export syntax.

NodeJS for whatever reason doesn't support at this time the ES6 `import/export` syntax you're employing.

Try the CommonJS syntax (`require/exports`):

```
const jsonToAim = (jsonObj) => {...}

//At the end of your file:
export {
 jsonToAim
}
```

Here's a [really good thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export) about the ES6 vs CommonJS export syntax.

Comment: hi! so I tried doing the export at the end, but I got the same error. I currently have jsonToAim defined as `function jsonToAim(jsonObj) {...}`. I was also wondering, why did you define the first line like that? thank you so much!

Comment: Did you change the function definition to `const jsonToAim = (jsonObj) => {...}` before trying again? You can define an 'anonymous' function like this: `(fooParam) => {return fooParam}` and then assign it to a const or var like I did above thanks to ES6 's arrow functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use ES Modules instead of CommonJS

Node.js uses by default Common js `require()`

That means that:

```
export function jsonToAim(jsonObj){...}
```

should be

```
function jsonToAim(jsonObj){...}

module.exports.jsonToAim = jsonToAim;
```

Later you import it with:

```
const { jsonToAim } = require(...);
```

However you can use ES modules in node.js too.

I have written an similar answer for this type of problem:

[ES6 imports for JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64275668/es6-imports-for-jwt/64275883#64275883)

Comment: Do I call the jsonToAim function like this? `jsonToAim(x)` or `jsonToAim.jsonToAim(x)` or something else? It doesn't seem to enter this function when i tried running it

Comment: just `jsonToAim()`. i have tested it it works @j.doe